# Duplicating a chrome user (incl. bookmarks, passwords etc)

Tags: google-chrome, user-profiles, user

I sometimes need to open the same sites on different sessions for testing purposes.
Until now I did it with an incognito window, but I'd prefer if it was through a different chrome user, which is more dynamic and comfortable.

Is it any way to duplicate an existing user with all of its data?
I tried a brute force approach of creating a new profile and copying all the contents from the first one, but obviously, that didn't work (I guess because the data is unique in some manner)

Thanks for your answers!